# How can I plot a set of points in 3d?

Tags: functional-analysis

durnig exams I often have the problem to visualize the sets I should work with, especially in 3D. So I wanted to ask if there is a trick on how to sketch the following set for example

$ G:=\{(x,y,z)^T \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2<4,~0<z<4-x^2-y^2\} $

I would also really like to know how I could plot this by using WolframAlpha?

Comment: It seems off-topic to ask about 3D plotting using WolframAlpha, though I can imagine having access to it during exams would simplify a large number of tasks.  In general there is no trick to visualizing 3D sets using pencil and paper, or rather the approaches (isometric drawing and orthographic projection) are reasonably well-known but not taught specifically in math courses.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Do you recognize the surface $z = x^{2} + y^{2}$? It is a paraboloid! The same applies to $z = -x^{2} - y^{2}$, which is the reflection of $z = x^{2} + y^{2}$ as to the plane $xy$. If you translate its vertice to $(0,0,4)$, you obtain the given surface when you restrict its domain to the circle $x^{2} + y^{2} < 4$.

Comment: This might help with visualization (and the general technique might be called finding cross-sections), but it avoids the issue of plotting.  I'll let the OP be the judge whether it helps.